# Get index of array element as Int

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have an array of `UIViewController` in my protocol

```
var viewControllers: [MyViewController] { get }
```

I want to get the index of item with specific ViewController

```
let idfx = viewModel.viewControllers.index(of: viewController as! MyViewController)
```

But the type of `idfx` is `Array.index`.

**How can I get the index of an array element as an Int?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't that it's of type `Array.index`, which is a typealias for `Int`, as Nonuld says. The problem is that it's an optional. You need to unwrap the optional somehow. One way is to use "if let" optional binding:

```
if let idfx = viewModel.viewControllers.index(of: viewController as! MyViewController) {
  print("view controller found at index \(idfx)") 
} else {
  print("View controller not found in array")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the type [`Array.Index` is a typealias to the type `Int`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/index), so you can do the same operation as if you had an integer with the result of the method `index(of:)`.

Comment: Beware: this answer ignores the fact the question assumption "But the type of idfx is Array.index" is false. The returned type is optional, see the accepted answer.